# How to Create job for De-identification template in GCP DLP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, masking, google-cloud-dlp

I am new to DLP so may have limited visibility w.r.t to **DLP** Services.

I have created one `DE-IDENTIFY Template` for data Masking. I want to use that `DE-IDENTIFY Template` over a few **BigQuery** tables but I am not getting any direct way to do that like the `INSPECT Template` that provides `INSPECT Job` in DLP itself.

***Do I need to write a custom job for all the De-identify use cases? if yes then where I can run that custom logic DataFlow, DataProc, GKE, Cloud Function or else ?***

I have checked the `Dataflow` template but that does not provide any template for Bigquery only. Most of the templates are for data ingestion such as from `Cloud Storage` to `BigQuery`. Not for the data already stored in BigQuery.

Is there anything that I am missing? I am using `asia-south1` region for the Testing. Please help me to understand the use case of it.

Comment: Not sure if it applies to your use case. If you don't need to remove the PII data from the table and masking/hashing is enough, you could use [dynamic data masking](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-data-masking-intro)

Comment: Cloud DLP doesn't "yet" support native de-id support of bigquery, but it's coming. Currently customers usually write their own dataflow templates to accomplish that goal.

Comment: @DiegoRodríguez Yes I am aware of Dynamic Data Masking but DDM provides limited feature and customization is not allowed such as I want to mask only 12 char in Credit card details

Comment: @JordannaChord you mean I have to write this login in ingestion job that is writing data into BigQuery.

Comment: Yes, that's one path. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dlp-dataflow-deidentification